# Pagination on terms aggregation java api

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

We have java api to get aggregation in elastic search

```
TermsAggregationBuilder aggrBuilder = AggregationBuilders.terms(bRuleCol.get(0)).field(firstField).size((int) _totalHits);
```

How to add pagination to this?

Update: 
Added below code,
    searchRequestBuilder.setFrom(pageNo).setSize(pageSize);

Resulting in below query

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "status.keyword": [
              "OPEN"
            ],
            "boost": 1
          }
        }
      ],
      "adjust_pure_negative": true,
      "boost": 1,
      "_name": "Query By SearchFilters"
    }
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "discrepancy.delta.deltaId": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "discrepancy.delta.deltaId.keyword",
        "size": 29,
        "min_doc_count": 1,
        "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
        "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
        "order": [
          {
            "_count": "desc"
          },
          {
            "_key": "asc"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But this query not taking size and from in to account, returning  all the results

Comment: What do you mean by pagination in this contex ? Can you be a bit more precise on what you intend to do ?

Comment: Hi Philippe, If I aggregate based on some field, it is getting around 500 counts, if GUI wants to send page number and page size how to accomodate it. For eg. if gui wants to show page 1 with count 10 and in second request with page 2( Paginated data)

Comment: You can choose how many result to return with aggregations. But I don't think you can select a range. Which means that you have to take all results from your query, store it somewhere (like in a `List<T>`) and request this list from each page you have. On your page 1, you request from index 0 to 10 in your least, in your page 2, from 11 to 20, so on and so on.